# Reading set of records from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to build a unix shell script and am stuck terribly.

My input file has multiple queries, present under their corresponding headings as:-
input filename:- query.txt

```
degree1              <------ heading(to be searched through out the file)
Select * from t1         <---- Start of Query(Start point of copy) 
go                     <------- End of query(End point of copy)

degree2
select * from t2
go

degree1
select * from t3
go

degree3
select * from t4
go
```

Now, I am supposed to fetch the query present under heading "degree1" and store it in some separate file.

Basically I am required to do the following things:-

```
i) write a loop that traverses through the file searching for all "degree1" & "degree2"
ii) after doing that, copy all present under degree1 till "go" keyword into another          
file.
iii) create multiple files if there exists more then one occurence of "degree1" in the     
query.txt file.
```

so as per the example above, i should be getting 4 different files i.e. 2 containing sql queries present under degree1, 1 for degree2 and another for degree 3.

I can provide more inputs if required.
I would really appreciate a prompt reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finds each `degree1` section and writes it to a separate file (files are named `output-#` where `#` starts at 1 and is incremented for each section found):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="";FS="\n"} /^degree1\n/ {c++; print $0 >"output-" c}' query.txt
```

In the example `query.txt` file, each section is separated by a blank line.  Because `awk`'s record separator is set to the empty string, `RS=""`, `awk` will read in a complete section at a time.  If then checks whether the section starts with `degree1` or not.  If it does, it increments a counter, `c`, and writes the section to a file called `output-#` where `#` is replaced by the value of the counter `c`.

To look for both the `degree1` and `degree2` sections in the same run requires only small changes:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="";FS="\n"} $1=="degree1" {c1++; print $0 >$1 "-" c1} $1=="degree2" {c2++; print $0 >$1 "-" c2}' query.txt
```

This creates as many files as there are occurrences of each section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the command is not generating any output. Although there is no syntax error but no output is getting generated.

Comment: My bad, I apologize for calling it "output". You are absolutely right, i require files only. However, I could see 5 files now in the directory i.e. degree1-1, degree1-2 and degree2-1 etc. but all contain "degree" keyword only. In place of keyword I desire for their corresponding queries.

Comment: @AmninderSingh On my computer, each of the files has all three lines.  The only reason that I can see for them to be missing would be if there is a problem with the record separator definition.  I have `RS=""` which makes `awk` read in a paragraph at a time and that is what it should print.  Without that statement, then the output would be what you see.

Comment: @AmninderSingh I am on linux using gawk. Are you on something else?  If so, maybe try `RS="\n\n"` instead.

Comment: @AmninderSingh Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` is quite simpler.

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{print $0 > $1".txt"}' query.txt
```

This will create 3 files named degree1.txt, degree2.txt and degree3.txt as per your sample input.

```
$ head degree*
==> degree1.txt <==
degree1
Select * from t1
go

degree1
select * from t3
go


==> degree2.txt <==
degree2
select * from t2
go


==> degree3.txt <==
degree3
select * from t4
go
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The command above is creating 5 files i.e. degree1.txt, degree2.txt,degree3.txt,select.txt and go.txt. Degree*.txt file contains "Degree" keyword only. Select.txt contains all select queries present in the file. Go.txt has keyword "Go" in it.